# NSUserDefaults lost after App Store update

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have strange issue where variables for settings stored with NSUserDefaults are reset or lost. This only happens when installing an update released through the App Store.

I found this old thread on Apple's discussion forum; https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1636574?tstart=0

It is pretty much the exact same problem I am facing. I can't reproduce the problem with the iOS emulator; so it seems like it works like intended here.

Has anyone had similar problems, and more specifically, what did you do to resolve this problem?

I am calling `NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`
 in my applications `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: did your certificate / appID / bundleID change for some reason?

Comment: No, no one of these have changed. I initially thought this was the culprit myself. Sorry for not stating in the first post.

Comment: mum weird.. no idea then :(

Comment: All the files stored in the Documents will be existing after the update. NSUserDefaults are stored in Library/Preferences/com.MyCompany.plist! So check out accordingly

Comment: Can you clarify? It is driving me crazy not to reliable know if I have made a mistake or something else is causing the problem. I don't know if customers will loose their settings, again, when they install a new update from the App Store.

Comment: Hi @Tobiaswk, could you managed to solve the problem?